# Eclipse c++, how to add std11?

Tags: c++, eclipse

**I have installed:**
*Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)*

And I'm tring to execute a working code (already tested).
So I have done: 
*File -> New -> C++ Project*
Than I click on next, next, finish... so without changing anything.

As it is suggested in http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ:
**Open Project Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->GCC C++ Compiler->Miscellaneous->Other Flags. Put "-std=c++0x" at the end.**
Than I did the following:
**Open Project Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->Cross G++ Compiler->Miscellaneous->Other Flags. Put "-std=c++0x" at the end.**
I have tried to put -std=c++11 instead of -std=c++0x but nothing changed.

But I still got the following on-the-fly in-the-editor suggestion:

> Symbol 'chrono' could not be resolved

The errors are like the following one: *"Function 'now' could not be resolved"*

No, Tom Mekken, I did not.
**How can I set up the paths of the chrono library ?**

Comment: Is this a real build error, or on-the-fly in-the-editor suggestion?

Comment: we've got [chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header) since 11, so  why not -std=c++11 or -std=c++14?

Comment: have you set the paths to your used libraries correctly? the error does not seem to have anything to do with the -std flag